# How do I load images with dispatch queue for screensavers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, screensaver

I am trying to code a screensaver that loads images from my website and displays them in a random order. The randomness and image acquiring is covered by my web API, but how to get it downloading without freezing the UI has gotten me truly stuck.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
- (void)animateOneFrame
{
    NSRect viewBounds = [self bounds];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_current_queue();

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSImage *image = [self extractImageFrom:@"my_url.com"];
        NSSize imageSize = [image size];            
        NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect( 0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height );

        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{    
            [image drawInRect:viewBounds fromRect:imageRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        });

    });
    return;
}
```

Here I tried to trigger the function that gets the image and caption on a separate queue. Then the image is to be drawn on the original view, but this is the issue.

Whenever select the final screenviewer plugin in the preference panel, the image is drawn on the preference panel's view (not the black preview rectangle). Similarly, when previewing the screensaver the image is not drawn, but whenever I quit the screensaver the preference panel's view is covered with the image.

It seems to me that the image is always being loaded and drawn, but not in the right queue/context? Instead of using the variable `queue` I also used `dispatch_get_main_queue()` with identical results. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is nothing wrong with your threading. It's the drawing that is the problem.

Your drawing call is without context. `drawInRect` is Quartz function that needs a graphic context. Usually it is used in the drawing methods of `NSView`.

You should subclass the view you are drawing to and give it a method like `updateWithImage:(NSImage*)image` where you do the drawing properly. Then you call that method on the main thread.

```
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
        [theCorrectView updateWithImage:image];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the drawing code to the overriden super view's drawRect function. Then call

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

on the main queue. It will schedule a new drawRect:(CGRect) call.

Comment: Tried `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];` and `[self setNeedsLayout:YES];` but unfortunately no success.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but maybe it helps. My startup is building a screensaver that can display web pages, it's called [Screensaver Ninja](https://screensaver.ninja), so that if you develop a page that does what you want using jQuery or any other usual web technologies and just display it. You can find more at https://screensaver.ninja.